# Multiplayer game on Google App Engine

Tags: python, api, google-app-engine

I would like to make a multiplayer game on the app engine. And the channel api gives me another reason to choose the app engine over a lot of other services. Has anyone tried this?

I understand how about go about a turn based game but I am stuck on how to go about something that has multiple users each contributing to others users experience. Any help would be appreciated.

1. Db modeling
2. Anything to keep in mind.
3. Js clients.

Comment: That's a question more suited for [Gamedev](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/).  They are more likely to answer you.

Comment: The product is just "App Engine", just like this isn't "the Stack Overflow".

Answer (score 4):

Interesting read over here at the appengine blog about a real time game on appengine...

http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2010/04/games-on-app-engine-interview-with-jay.html

Answer (score 2):

I have a prototype implementation details of multiuser chat room (or a game room) on my blog post at http://blog.myblive.com/2010/12/multiuser-chatroom-with-app-engine.html. This and the second part of post http://blog.myblive.com/2011/01/multiuser-chatroom-with-app-engine.html shall be able to tell you pretty much about the implementation details.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [Channel API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/overview.html#Example_Tic_Tac_Toe_Application), it has a very good description of what it's current capabilities are.

The [TIC TAC TOE](http://code.google.com/p/channel-tac-toe/) example project (created by moishel, one of the creators of google's Channel API) contains a two player game that utilizes the Channel API.  It uses the Channel API to communicate game states to both players.  Mind the "Caveats" section -- "One Client Per Client ID" and "One Client Per Channel Per Page".